# codeigniter retrieve parameter values passed from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've passed some parameters from a view to a controller function. i see them in the url like : `.../view/a1312014031`
but i'm not able to use them in the function

here is the view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>visiteur/view/<?php echo $id; echo $mois; ?>" class='btn btn-primary'>Mettre en paiement </a>
```

here is the controller function

```
public function view($id = '', $mois = '') {
    ......
    $page = 'visiteur_liste';
    $this->load->view('visiteur/' . $page, $data);
    ....
    }
```

after clicking the link i get  url with the parameters.../view/a1312014031
is there a solution to use those parameters in the function without using the session?
thanks for your time

Comment: where are you using session here?

Comment: And also, you'l need to separate both parameter in url by "/", like, `<?php echo $id."/"; echo $mois; ?>`

Comment: i'm not using session, i know it's one solution. but i'm wondering if i can do it without...

Comment: i've tried this but i get Undefined variable: id! is it possible to pass thos parameters to the controller another way than the url

Comment: OK, Number 1: you pass methods FROM controller TO view... Number 2: if your getting undefined variabel $id.. (assume this is in your VIEW, not your CONTROLLER because you define $id in the controller params...) means you have probably not passed the data to the view properly, it should be passed as key=>value array pair `$data = array('id'=>1234);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, then

You'l need to separate your parameter value in your hyperlink by "/", like:

**HTML**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>visiteur/view/<?php echo $id.'/'.$mois; ?>" class='btn btn-primary'>Mettre en paiement </a>
```

**PHP**

```
public function view($id = '', $mois = '') { //function in CodeIgniter Controller (visiteur)
    ......
    $page = 'visiteur_liste';
    $this->load->view('visiteur/' . $page, $data);
    ....
}
```

**ANOTHER WAY: PASS DATA USING GET PARAMETERS:**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>visiteur/view?id=<?php echo $id.'&mois='.$mois; ?>" class='btn btn-primary'>Mettre en paiement </a>
```

**GET IN CodeIgniter**

```
public function view() {  //function in CodeIgniter Controller (visiteur)
        $id=$this->input->get("id"); // or, $id=$_GET["id"];
        $mois=$this->input->get("mois"); // or, $mois=$_GET["mois"];

}
```

Comment: @Log1c I want to use second method. its not working for me? shows page not found error. how to resolve it?

Comment: I think you didn't rewrote URLs to remove `index.php` from URL. In my example I didn't mensioned. So your URL should be like this--> `http://your.domain.com/index.php/controller_name/function?param=param_value&param2=value2`

Comment: Can you tell me your URL ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>visiteur/view/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $mois; ?>" 
   class='btn btn-primary'>Mettre en paiement </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works partly, i get this url ..view/a131/201403 but when i echo $mois and $id in the controler function, i only get the value of the second parameter ($mois) which is 201403 in the url. if i put $id at the second place like <?php echo $mois  ;?>/<?php echo $id; ?>, i only get $id value but not $mois.

Comment: try this in controller public function view($id =null,$mois=null)